# mongodb update and $set overwrites the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, edit

assume I have a document as;

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: alex, 
  age: 39,
  surname: felix
  address: [
   { 
     type: "home"
     street: "blabla"
   }
  ]
}
```

When I wrote the query as;

```
db.collection.update({id: 1 , adress.type: "home"} ,  { $set : {adress: { street: "test"}});
```

It changes the document as;

```
{
  id: 1,
  adress: [
      street: test
  ]
}
```

However I just want to set the part of the document, just want to change the street name but this query overwrites the document.

How can I edit the partial part of the document in `mongodb` with `update`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
db.collection.update( 
  { id: 1, "address.type" : "home" } , 
  {$set : {"address.$.street" : "test"}}
);
```

Read more from [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#definition)

Comment: yes, this is the answer . but why? rather than {adress: { street: "test"}} ""address.$.street"" changes the whole logic.

Comment: Since it's an array, we must update proper indexed value according to query.

Answer (score 0):

Updating items at a position in an array can be done using the positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator

```
db.collection.update( 
    {id: 1 , adress.type: "home"}, 
    { $set: { "adress.$.street": "test" } }
)
```

!Note, this only works when ONE (1) sub-document is found